# Failed to scan JAR when rename war

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a project which generate a war file. I customized my war name in my pom like this :

```
<build>
    <finalName>MyTestWar</finalName>
```

When i build my project with maven, it generates a war file named `MyTestWar.war`.

When I put my war file into `%CATALINA_HOME%/webapps`and start tomcat I keep getting `WARNING: Failed to process JAR` on my jars which are in `WEB-INF/lib` of my war file.

At the end of the logs tomcat give me `SEVERE: Error getConfigured` and then `SEVERE: Context [MyTestWar] startup failed due to previous errors`
Problem is that when I generate my war files with it's pom artifact name everything will be ok.

I don't know where to look for solution.

This is what tomcat log in catalina.log

```
WARNING: Failed to scan JAR [jndi:/localhost/MyTestWar/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar] from WEB-INF/lib
java.io.FileNotFoundException: jndi:/localhost/MyTestWar/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
```

Comment: Can you post the full logs that are of concern here? Which JAR; your own?

Comment: I edited my post.
As you can see its a third party jar i added to my project.
There is lots of this error on different jar files.